# What should you consider while constructing a Gaussian prior for the binned fit?

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, prior

I need to make Bayesian fit of the binned data. The model is simply linear function  (background) + Gaussian (signal). I want to set a Gaussian prior on the mean of the Gaussian from the model. 
What shall I consider while constructing the Gaussian prior? Shall I consider the bin width of the data for its width?

Comment: Any prior is an acceptable choice from the foundational point of view but using the data to set the prior is not.